# How to take string but only with dot in Python Panadas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
--------
Ul
UL.
ul.
aa
```

And I would like to select only rows where in col1 I have "UL." or "AA" case = False (nevermind whether big or small lether). Be aware that I would liek to have "UL." there is dot next to UL.

I use code like below:

```
df[df['col1'].str.contains("aa|UL.", na = False, case = False)]
```

But when I use this code as a result I have all rows from col1 in df because above code take all UL, and I need to take only UL with dot -> "UL."

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a special character in regex which you need to escape with a `\`.

```
df[df['col1'].str.contains("aa|UL\.", na = False, case = False)]

  col1
2  UL.
3  ul.
4  aa
```

Comment: Great! thank you! for a 8 minutes I will be able to give you best answer!